# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when assigning new arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to sort one array to two other arrays that have to be exact length. Why am I getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at Tal.main(Tal.java:39)` when running this? I know there is better way to solve this task but I am not allowed to. I have to do it this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many random numbers from 0 to 999? ");
    int amount = in.nextInt();

    int lowerCounter = 0;
    int higherCounter = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[amount];
    System.out.print("Here is the random numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        numbers[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");

        if (numbers[i] <= 499) {
            lowerCounter++;
        }
        else {
            higherCounter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");


    int[] numbersLow = new int[lowerCounter];
    int[] numbersHigh = new int[higherCounter];
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] <= 499)
        {
            numbersLow[i] = numbers[i];
        } else {
            numbersHigh[i] = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.print("These "+ lowerCounter +" numbers are from 0 to 499: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersLow.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(numbersLow[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("These "+ higherCounter +" numbers are from 500 to 999: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersHigh.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(numbersHigh[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, how do you expect us to know what `Tal.java:39` is from your posted code?

Comment: `numbersLow[i]` can throw an exception because `i < numbers.length`, and `lowerCounter <= numbers.length` by definition.

Comment: I can sure do that, but then my new arrays won't be exactly filled.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that `numbers.length` is always less than or equal to `lowerCounter` and `higherCounter`? Otherwise, it will access a higher index on those array which doesn't exist, which will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping variables are not correct. You should fix your code in order to have 2 different counters for both arrays and one counter to loop through the main one.

```
lowerCounter=higherCounter=0;
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (numbers[i] <= 499) {
       numbersLow[lowerCounter++] = numbers[i];
   } else {
       numbersHigh[higherCounter++] = numbers[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: You are my God! Thank you. It solved the problem.:))

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Java 8 :

```
int[] lowerThan500 = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(i -> i < 500).toArray();
```

Less code, less errors.

Or :

```
long nbLessThan500  = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(i -> i < 500).count();
```

Comment: Please read the question before answering !!! This is what the OP said "I know there is better way to solve this task but I am not allowed to. I have to do it this way."

Comment: This is sure the best way to filter, however I am not allowed to use such technique. My teachers want us to understand for-loops and arrays the "hard" way. :)

Comment: @superior OK, sorry. I still let the answer because too few developers use Java 8 and it might be interesting for future googlers.